# Azure DevOps: Getting an error while trying to update Work Item State using API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to write a code to update a work item state through Azure DevOps rest API.
I am getting an error (400).

This is my code to invoke the service:

```
string updateFeaturesStateBody = "
[
    {
        "op": "test",
        "path": "/rev",
        "value": "4"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.State",
        "value": "Blocked"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Reason",
        "value": "State changed as part of PWR planning"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.History",
        "value": "State changed as part of PWR planning"
    }
]";

StringContent wibatchContent = new StringContent(updateFeaturesStateBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await HttpClient.PatchAsync($"/{Org}/_apis/wit/workitems/{ID}?api-version=6.0", wibatchContent);
```

I always get the response: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'

Anyone can help me figure what is the problem?

Comment: Hi Annat, any update on this question, have you checked the answer I posted? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally understood what was the problem:

I had to change this line:

`StringContent wibatchContent = new StringContent(updateFeaturesStateBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

to this line:

`StringContent wibatchContent = new StringContent(updateFeaturesStateBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");`

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons for the 400 error, please share the detailed error message if possible. Please make sure that the state you want to modify exists and the preconditions for modifying the state are met.

What I can tell from your code is that you are not specifying the proper header.

This rest api has requirements for the request body type, you must specify it.

The below code works fine on my side:

```
using RestSharp;
using System;

namespace ChangeStatus
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            string OrgName = "<organization name>";
            string ProjectName = "<project name>";
            string workitem_id = "<workitem id>";
            string state_tochange = "<valid value of workitem>";
            string PAT = "<PAT token here>";
            var client = new RestClient("https://dev.azure.com/"+OrgName+"/"+ProjectName+"/_apis/wit/workitems/"+workitem_id+"?api-version=6.0");
            var request = new RestRequest("https://dev.azure.com/"+OrgName+"/"+ProjectName+"/_apis/wit/workitems/"+workitem_id+"?api-version=6.0", Method.Patch);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+PAT);
            var body = @"
                " + "\n" +
                            @"    [{
                " + "\n" +
                            @"        ""op"": ""add"",
                " + "\n" +
                            @"        ""path"": ""/fields/System.State"",
                " + "\n" +
                            @"        ""value"": """+
                                                        $"{state_tochange}"+
                            @"""
                " + "\n" +
                            @"    }]";
            request.AddParameter("application/json-patch+json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);


            var response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the support.
Tested it - got the following exception:
"Request failed with status code Unauthorized".

My Token has permission for "Read, Write & Manage" for Work Items. any suggestion?

Comment: For the code posted in the question, the error message in the exception is:
"Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)."
(Inner Exception is null)